# how to return a variable outside of javascript function that is inside a function?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-geocoder

So I have

```
  function find_coord(lat, lng) {
              var smart_loc;
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode( { 'latLng': latlng }, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                smart_loc = new smart_loc_obj(results);
            } else {
                smart_loc = null;
            }
        });

        return smart_loc;
}
```

I want to return the smart_loc variable/object but it is always null because the scope of the function(results, status) doesn't reach the smart_loc declared in the find_coord function.  So how do you get a variable inside the function(results, status) out?

Comment: I don't think it is an scope issue. But rather a I'm not defined yet issue. What does `geocoder.geocode` do? Something like an AJAX call?

Comment: You cannot do that.  The "geocode()" function is **asynchronous**, which means that it does not run immediately; it's run when Google returns results.

Comment: but the geocode isn't run until the function is run, and geocoder is from google maps geocoder

Comment: The callback function for the geocode call is run when Google responds to your request. It's not synchronous; it can happen many, many milliseconds after your "geocode()" function runs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
var smart_loc;

function find_coord(lat, lng) {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'latLng': latlng }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            smart_loc = new smart_loc_obj(results);
        } else {
            smart_loc = null;
        }
    });
}
```

Or if you need to run a function when smart_loc changes:

```
function find_coord(lat, lng, cb) {
          var smart_loc;
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'latLng': latlng }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            smart_loc = new smart_loc_obj(results);
        } else {
            smart_loc = null;
        }

        cb(smart_loc);
    });
}
```

then call:

```
find_coord(lat, lng, function (smart_loc) {
    //
    // YOUR CODE WITH 'smart_loc' HERE
    //
});
```